# Best practice for 2 kV enclosure

Tags: transformer, high-voltage

I'm making a Lichtenberg machine from a microwave transformer, and I wanted to put my setup in a enclosure to make it safer. The input voltage is 120 V AC and the output voltage is around 2200 V AC. For a high voltage project, is wood or plastic an acceptable material for an enclosure for this project?

Comment: how thick? if protection is important, consider insulators with rated dielectric strength (V/thickness).  Be aware that it is affected by temperature.

Comment: Consider using multiple insulators - while a thin plastic insulator will easily withstand 2kV it could become damaged or contaminated.  ‘Double insulated’ equipment requires that all conductors have two methods of insulation so that a user can not be exposed if one insulator fails.  You could visualise an insulating box but inside the box all conductors are inaccessible, either covered or in a position that you couldn’t touch with a finger.

Comment: Glass is a good insulator,  Jay probably has a 10" or larger glass platter that he's not using anymore.

Answer (score 12):

A microwave oven transformer has one high voltage terminal connected to ground and the other free.

So you want a grounded enclosure with an insulated platform for the work. and some sort on interlock that turns off the transformer if you open the door.

Where have I seen that before?

Comment: This is the correct answer. A grounded metal enclosure with holes small enough to keep fingers and knitting needles out.

Comment: for those that haven't noticed I was alluding to re-using the microwave cabinet, it already has a door with switches that used to connect to the transformer. even a glass insulating platform.

Answer (score 2):

Plastic would be your first choice. Plastic is normally a water ( and humidity) repellent. Wood could be OK as long as its not raining on your device. Wood is OK if completely dry and keep indoor. I've used wood box to enclose a HV transformer once and didn't have any problem even with 240VAC going through the wood via iron nails. Not a recommended practice but just to say that wood is quite a good insulator when dry. ( Dryness is a Must ).

If your device catches rain or any other source of high humidity there are risk of current leakage. Whether you use plastic or wood just make sure that all wires are of good quality, particularly the insulation. Keep all connections adequate distance from each other. Do not use staples to hold wires in the box. A nail into a wire at 2000 volts is not a good idea. The main safety idea here is insulation. One good practice is to utilize Plastic Tie Wrap to hold wires. And keep High Voltage wires distance apart as practical as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that using wood here is a good idea. It tends to draw moisture from its environment, thereby lowering its insulation capabilities. And if it is dry (i.e. when it is a good insulator), then it tends to burn. So no good properties for an experiment where you might experience some sparks to fly.

I would generally recommend a good plastic enclosure and (as others already said) you should probably consider using double insulation. Ready-made plastic enclosures are not so expensive.

2 kV can behave in unexpected ways, and that can be extremely dangerous. Maybe you could ask an electrician to assist you in bootstrapping your experiment. At least, you should probably have *some/any* person with you, just in case anything goes wrong. I mention this, because in my family one person died (back in the late 1990s) when experimenting with a high voltage component sourced from an old microwave oven...

Have fun, but take care :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of enclosuring the transformer, I would install it on a piece of wood and insulate everything else: workbench where the setup is (lots of plastic), yourself (rubber boots & thick rubber gloves) and the transformer connectors (shrink tube + lots of tape on top of it). Use plastic rod to move electrodes live and use good quality wire rated for high voltage